# Error in installing pymssql 1.0.2 on Windows 2003 x64

Tags: python, pymssql

I am trying to install the latest version of pymssql (1.0.2) in my Windows 2003 x64.
   However, I am constantly getting this error:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_mssql' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG "-Ic:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tool
s\DevTools\Include" -Ic:\mssql7\DevTools\Include -Id:\DEVEL\pymssql-DEVTOOLS\INCLUDE -Ic:\Python27\include -Ic:\Python27\PC /Tcmssqldbmodule.c /Fobuil
d\temp.win32-2.7\Release\mssqldbmodule.obj
mssqldbmodule.c
mssqldbmodule.c(50) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlfront.h': No such file or directory
error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
```

Any ideas? Isn't sqlfront.h included in the installation of visual studio 2k8 (or any visual studios)

Thank you!

Comment: You need the Microsoft SQL Server 2000 Developer Edition. Freetds might also work; at least it does with latest versions of pymssql.

Comment: I have Microsoft SQL Server 2008 installed...shouldn't that be OK already?

Comment: I don't think SQL 2008 will do. I put binaries linked against SQL 2000 at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymssql. Don't know if they work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2008, Windows 7 64 and Python 2.7 (32 bits).

These were the steps I followed to solved it:

1. Install Visual Studio 2008 (32 bits).
2. Install Visual Studio 6.
3. Install Python 2.7 (32 bits)
4. Download pymssql (the same package you downloaded)
5. Try to compile the source code (the same you did when you got the error, you will get it again).
6. At the same directory where setup.py is, you should find a file named **mssqldbmodule.c**, open it.
7. Change the lines `#include <sqlfront.h>` and `#include <sqldb.h>` To `#include "sqlfront.h"` and `#include "sqldb.h"` So the compiler will look for sqlfront.h and sqldb.h files locally.
8. Copy the files **sqlfront.h** and **sqldb.h** from: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\Include` (Visual Studio 6 installation) To you local directory (where setup.py is).
9. Copy the file **NTWDBLIB.LIB** from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\Lib`
   To your local directory.
10. Run again `setup.py install`

This way you will compile the library using the deprecated **NTWDBLIB** which is the one used by pymssql.

Answer (score 0):

The directory `<pymssql root>\freetds\vs2008_32\`  (or `<pymssql root>\freetds\vs2008_64\` if you use 64bits python) has not been set for header files and libs yet I think.

About freetds, please check the "Building FreeTDS" part of README_building_and_developing.rst.